# Control android by sms

Tags: android, sms, controls

I'm doing my fyp in Android app and I'm still learning the whole deal, and I'm welling to learn it, my question is how can you make an Android based device to respond to predefined SMS codes to do a specific function?

I would appreciate any related info whether task related or programming related.

Have read few books so far but didn't find any info regarding controlling the phone with SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to listen for SMS and and execute accordingly. [This article](http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android) may help you get started.